# Periodical and continuous function

Tags: functions

I have stumbled upon the following problem:
Given $f(x) = \mathbb R  \to \mathbb R, f(x) = (-1)^{[x]}(x+a\cdot[\frac x2]+b)+3,$ with $ a, b \in \mathbb R $
And $ A = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2 | f $ *periodical of period 2 and continuous in* $x=1$$ \} $
Calculate $ S = \sum_{(a,b)\in A}(a+b) $.
Where $[x]$ is the integer part(truncation) of $x$.

I have figured out that $f$ breaks into something like this: $f(x) = \begin{cases} x+a\cdot\frac x2 + b + 3, \text{$x$ even} \\ -x-a\cdot[\frac x2] - b + 3 , \text{$x$ odd} \end{cases} $ but I am stuck now. I can't link it to the period and the fact that it's continuous in $x=1$. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $[x]$ denoting?

Comment: $[x]$ is the integer part (truncation) of $x$.

Comment: Ok, so the closest integer to $x$, right?

Comment: @Daniel No, the biggest integer smaller or equals to $x$

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's the biggest integer lesser (or equal) than $x$. Example $[3.5] = 3$ and $[-3.5] = -4$.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Weird notation for that then, I'm more used to $\lfloor x\rfloor$

Comment: @Daniel Our country seems to not use that notation, sorry. It goes like this: $[x] = \begin{cases} \lceil x \rceil , x \lt 0 \\ 0 , x =0 \\ \lfloor x \rfloor, x \gt 0 \end{cases} $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $f(x+2)=f(x)$ we get $(-1)^{[x+2]}(x+ 2 + a\cdot[\frac {x+2} 2]+b)+3=(-1)^{[x]}(x+a\cdot[\frac x2]+b)+3$ from here $(-1)^{[x]}(x+ 2 + a\cdot([\frac x2]) + 1)+b)+3=(-1)^{[x]}(x+a\cdot[\frac x2]+b)+3$ and from here $a=-2$, so $f(x)=(-1)^{[x]}(x-2\cdot[\frac x2]+b)+3$. Now just use the continuity in $x=1$ to get $b$.

**Note:** I used the fact that $[x + k]=[x] + k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I think you forgot to replace $x$ by $x+2$ in the part $x + a\cdot$...

Comment: @Daniel Right, thanks.

Comment: Thank you ! I figured it out now.